# Android Studio update to version 3.1 error

Tags: android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio to the lastest version 3.1 and I cannot do anything because of the following error:

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom'.
```

It is also saying:

```
Gradle project sync failed.
```

This is how my error looks like:

[image]

And

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add below changes in your project gradle for maven dependency and try either it works or not.

```
ext.androidAnnottationVersion = 'version here'

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$androidAnnottationVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$androidAnnottationVersion"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now I'm having another error: `org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out`.

Comment: If it works then please upvote so that other can be benefited. And for second issue are you using old jdk can you upgrade your jdk and try?

Comment: @loanan can you show your updated gradle file I am having same issue  but this could't resolve my issue

Comment: I have managed to make it work but not using those dependencies. I have restarted Android Studio several times to start syncing again each time. After 4-5 restarts, I didn't get that error but I got the error above. I updated the jdk, as 0xalihn advices and now it works fine. Voted up for that suggest. Thanks!

Comment: @NakAndroidDev Please see my above comment.

Comment: @loana P. in you added the above code in project level or app level; please specify. I tried in app level gradle but still the above issue exist

Comment: @NakAndroidDev I did, but didn't help. So I removed them. As a conclusion is working without those lines.

Comment: what your jdk version I am using JDK 9.0.1

Comment: @NakAndroidDev Same version JDK 9.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167625/discussion-between-nak-android-dev-and-ioana-p).